# Android proguard enabled APK size increases on adding a new library

Tags: android, apk, proguard, android-multidex, classyshark

We have several dependency libraries in our APK and have enabled proguard and multi dex. ***We have 3 dex files***. **We intend to keep the APK size as small as possible.**

We are currently trying to integrate a 'new Ads SDK'.

While integrating, we are seeing an abnormal increase in the size of our APK after including the dependency library.

The memory footprint of the library is around **~280 KB in a sample app**. But when we add the same dependency in our app, our apk size increases by **595 KB**. Their proguard rule keeps all their classes.

On debugging with APK analyzer in android studio and classyshark, we observed that the size of other packages and classes like facebook, google, glide etc in our dex files are increasing in size.

However, their method counts remain same. This could only mean the proguard compression is being compromised. So, APK size ***increase*** is like **280 KB (ads sdk) + X [315 KB]**. *We are trying to eliminate the unnecessary 315 KB increase in the APK size.*

Any leads on investing the cause of this abnormal increase in size would be appreciated.

Please share any dex options/proguard optimizations which might help in this scenario.

**UPDATE:**
The proguard rules of the SDK in question looks like this:

-keep class com.example.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.example.**

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use `consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'` instead of the default?

Comment: No, we dont use consumerProguardFiles. We add each library's proguard rules to our main proguard rules files.

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: We have multiple library modules (more than 10) in our project and its a commercial application. Unfortunately, I can not share the source code. But if you have any thoughts/questions, I can definitely share more information.

Comment: "Their proguard rule keeps all their classes.", — I suggest you edit your question with exact contents of that rule(s). If you don't want to reveal the specific ads SDK, you can carefully replace real package names with `com.example`. Also does the library itself has consumer proguard files inside it's aar file? If so, post it as well.

Comment: Added the proguard rules as well.

Comment: I would print the code in bytecode format (using dexdump or baksmali) before and after the change and look into the diff. Can you share a diff sample?

Answer (score 0):

What i can infer from your post is most likely some of the rules added in proguard as part of new lib config causes decrease in code shrink for lib like facebook , google. It is difficult to avoid 3rd party sdk rules, however you can still shrink your apk using other approach if that is not yet adopted by your app. If your graphic resources still use PNG change them to webP it would reduce the size of apk.

Also check for common lib if present as part of ads sdk. Once we had seen two version of google play services in our app and we had to exclude the one present in sdk dependency via gradle config.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. We have already covered most of the bases to reduce the APK size like converting our resources to webp and svg, eliminating unused resources, string optimizations, proguard etc. But this is a strange problem we have recently observed